# Gridview delete button not working

Tags: gridview, sqldatasource

I am trying to make my webpage able to edit a database (ImportantNews) from an administration page using grid view. When i click delete however it just refreshes the page and does not delete anything. I am using ASP.Net 2.0

**Gridview**

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
  AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" 
                    SortExpression="Title" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Content" HeaderText="Content"
                    SortExpression="Content" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br/>
<b>SqlDataSource</b>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [ImportantNews]" 
     DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [ImportantNews] WHERE [Content] = @Content AND [Title] = @Title">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Title" Type="string"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Content" Type="string"/>
    </DeleteParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I did what people sugested and got this error
Must declare the scalar variable "@Content". 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@Content".

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@Content".]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +1953274
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +4849707
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +194
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2392
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async) +192
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +317
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDbCommand(DbCommand command, DataSourceOperation operation) +386
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteDelete(IDictionary keys, IDictionary oldValues) +303
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Delete(IDictionary keys, IDictionary oldValues, DataSourceViewOperationCallback callback) +89
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleDelete(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex) +714
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +869
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +207
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

Answer (score 0):

Try adding DataKeyNames="Content"